# Gson TypeAdapter not working for null with annotation JsonAdapter

Tags: java, json, gson

[image]**TypeAdapter nullSafe skipping custom handling code.**

I have written IntegerTypeAdapter and use as annotation to achieve below output, but written code in gson library completely not allowing null handling with annotation configuration.

If I uncomment line 1,2,4 and comment line 3, then still i don't achieve my desire output.

> When i debug library code at line number 189 (given screenshot image)
> not reaching to my custom Adapter code so null handling not working
> with annotation. Is there any alternative way to achieve desired
> output based on annotation configuration?

Desired Output:

1. catlives - "" (As used annotation and have null value)
2. phone - 89    (As used annotation and have Integer value)
3. rank -        (No key present because not using annotation and have null value)

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
class CatDetails {
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private String email;
    //@JsonAdapter(EmptyIfNullIntegerTypeAdapter.class) //1
    private Integer catlives;
    //@JsonAdapter(EmptyIfNullIntegerTypeAdapter.class) //2
    private Integer phone;
    private String city;
    private Integer rank;
    private Boolean likesMice;
}


public class EmptyIfNullIntegerTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Integer> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Integer value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            out.value("");
            return;
        }
        out.value(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            in.nextNull();
            return 0;
        }
        return in.nextInt();
    }

}


public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        CatDetails user = new CatDetails("cat007", "YUI", "abc.cat@gmail.com", null,89, "new",null, true);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().registerTypeAdapter(Integer.class, new EmptyIfNullIntegerTypeAdapter()).create(); //3
        //Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create(); //4
        String json = gson.toJson(user);
        System.out.println(json);
    }

}


Currently code giving below Output:
{
  "name": "cat007",
  "breed": "YUI",
  "email": "abc.cat@gmail.com",
  "catlives": "",
  "phone": 89,
  "city": "new",
  "rank": "",
  "likesMice": true
}
```

Looking below output with annotation:

Special care with two Integer fields (catlives & phone) only *if value is null it write empty string.* Whereas for other Integer field when value null then work like default (skip key-value pair).

```
{
  "name": "cat007",
  "breed": "YUI",
  "email": "abc.cat@gmail.com",
  "catlives": "",
  "phone": 89,
  "city": "new",
  "likesMice": true
}
```

Comment: 1) If I'm not mistaken, this is a Gson design flaw probably here: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/bab0f5a1f7040389eb8fe0cb417ba1854e33dbd0/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java#L219 . 2) Why are you trying to write an empty string for an integer? 3) In general, try assigning the default field values to work around. 4) If neither works for you (and you still think string-integer coercion is totally fine), create a specialized DTO class for `CatDetails`.

Comment: I agree for point -1 but when writing code registerTypeAdapter then work perfectly but it work for all Integer fields.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm talking about: `@JsonAdapter` probably can't work for null fields. So you seem to have ran into a Gson bug but I cannot double check it right now, something is telling me so. Also, consider the point #4 and points #2 and #3 together: extract a specialized DTO (Data Transfer Object) class to map all the fields that Gson can support without tricks, probably holding the integer-string coercion mapping and keeping default values where necessary.

Comment: Sorry for partial reply.. I can choose other points.. But still some challenge.. 2) Actually target system accepting same. 3) Default value give a different answer when we pass zero. Because zero is also a valid value. 4) I can do if there is small set of object family tree. After that still i need to write ObjectMapper to which transfer my data.

Comment: 3) Ah, sorry, I seem to have missed your very point. So, you can't pass `null` just because the target system works so. 4) Well, not sure if we're on the same page, but I still believe you need a specialized DTO (for robustness, it may have a single constructor to make sure everything is mapped properly; using MapStruct or a similar tool to remove the imperative boilerplate). You can also try using `JsonSerializer` for the `CarDetails` class and do the coercion right there, but it also has some drawbacks (no `@SerializedName` support, etc)... Or switch from Gson...

Comment: I opened it as a bug - https://github.com/google/gson/issues/2088. Let me check, why TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper not interfering if null occurs but TypeAdapter skipping null value. And there is no overloaded method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [`@JsonAdapter#nullSafe`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html#nullSafe()) to `false`, otherwise Gson by default makes your specified adapter null-safe. For example:

```java
@JsonAdapter(value = EmptyIfNullIntegerTypeAdapter.class, nullSafe = false)
private Integer catlives;
```

Comment: Thank you @Marcono1234. I didn't check other properties of annotations.

Answer (score 1):

**- JsonAdapter property `nullSafe = false` solved my problem.**

```
@JsonAdapter(value = EmptyIfNullIntegerTypeAdapter.class, nullSafe = false)
private Integer catlives;
```

> But the same does not work with JsonSerializer.

```
public class EmptyIfNullTypeAdapter<T> implements JsonSerializer<T> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(T src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        if (src == null) {
            return new JsonPrimitive("");
        } else {
            switch (typeOfSrc.getTypeName()) {
            case "java.lang.Integer":
                return new JsonPrimitive(Integer.parseInt(src.toString()));
            case "java.lang.Long":
                return new JsonPrimitive(Long.parseLong(src.toString()));
            case "java.lang.Double":
                return new JsonPrimitive(Double.parseDouble(src.toString()));
            default:
                return new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
    @JsonAdapter(value=EmptyIfNullTypeAdapter.class, nullSafe=false)
    private Integer catlives;
    @JsonAdapter(value=EmptyIfNullTypeAdapter.class, nullSafe=false)
    private Integer phone;
```

Comment: Cool. Sorry for the confusion and the misleading I suggested to you...

Comment: No problem @user12232870

Comment: As a minor suggestion now, `JsonPrimitive` has a constructor overload for `java.lang.Number`, so once `src instanceof Number`, you can simply cast `src` and pass it to the constructor. This will save unnecessary conversions and will support all numbers.

Comment: I would have to use 'extends TypeAdapter<Integer>' and other types ... but not 'implements JsonSerializer<T>' because 'nullSafe' property not working with JsonSerializer.

Comment: JsonAdapter's `nullSafe` not working with `JsonSerializer` is a [known bug](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1553), which is unfortunately not fixed yet.